# Good practice usin exit in php

Tags: php

I'm making a simple login system and I'm using exit but I'm not sure is this way its the correct way to use exit.

```
<?php

    if(fromLogin()){
        session_start();
        error_reporting(0);

        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345', 'seocom');

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "connection_error";
            exit;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username = '$username'";
        if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
            echo "connection_error";
            exit;  
        }
        if ($result->num_rows === 0 ){
            echo "user_error"; 
            exit;
        }  

        $user_pass = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if($user_pass['username'] == $username && md5($password) == $user_pass['password']){
            $_SESSION['logued'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            echo "logued";
        }else{
            echo "user_error"; 
        }
        $result->free();
        $mysqli->close();
    }else{
        header("Location: login.html");
        exit;
    }

    //comprueba si viene de login.html
    function fromLogin(){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/seocom_login/login.html";
    }
```

This is a correct way or I  should use nested if and else instead? I m not sure if  call exit on every possible error is a good approach to use the exit function.

Comment: `md5()`is obsolete for hashing passwords and should *not be used*. PHP provides [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

In procedural code like in your case, it is bad practice. Because exit endpoints really increase read, debug and refactoring complexity.

Sometimes in functions, you can use "return" to stop executing function code.

p.s.

You can think about decoupling your logic on atomic functions. This decrease reading complexity. Or you can think about OOP methods.